# How to install Emmet with gedit text editor in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: software-sources, gedit, plugins, text-editor

I am using Ubuntu 12.04. I came to know about [emmet](http://emmet.io/) plugin. Which is really awesome for writing markups. As I am a developer I am using gedit with [zencoding](https://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/) plugin to write markup easily. Now as I heared about [emmet](http://emmet.io/), I want to use it. But can someone kindly tell me how can I make it install with Gedit and use it?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge no-one has done a full port of emmet to gedit yet

there is a version of zen coding that will work with gedit 3.x

https://github.com/mtrovo/zen-coding-gedit3

Comment: Doesn't work with the latest Gedit 3.22. So it is probably defunct since at least 3.14 which is their latest [API change](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gedit/API-Changes).